# For loop not running under a void - fight scenario

Tags: c++, for-loop, void

I'm new to C++ and I am having some trouble with an assignment. Here is my program so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void fight(string heroName, int arrowCount, int enemyCount);
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    string heroName = "Legolas";
    int arrowCount = 3;
    int enemyCount = 3;

    cout << "Welcome to the Arena, the battle will begin shortly." << endl;
    system("pause");
    cout << "\nToday's competitors: " << "\n" << heroName << "\n" << "3 Orcs" << endl;

    system("pause");

    cout << "\n" << heroName << " will be given 3 arrows" << "\n" << "3 Orcs will be given daggers. \n";

    system("pause");

    cout << "\nThe battle begins in...\n 3...\n  2...\n   1..." << endl;

    system("pause");

    fight(heroName, arrowCount, enemyCount);
}

void fight(string heroName, int arrowCount, int enemyCount) {

    for (int x = arrowCount; x <= 0; x--) {

        if (arrowCount == 3) {
            cout << "\n" << heroName << " fires arrow at Azog." << "\nAzog has fallen due to lobotomy by arrow." << "\nLegolas notices he has 2 arrows remaining." << endl;
            system("pause");
        }

        if (arrowCount == 2) {
            cout << "\n" << heroName << " fires arrow at Dular." << "\nDular has taken an arrow to the knee and is now longer an adventurer." << "\nLegolas notices he has 1 arrow remaining." << endl;
            system("pause");
        }

        if (arrowCount == 1) {
            cout << "\n" << heroName << " fires arrow at Nagrub." << "\nNagrub has lost his testicles." << "\nLegolas notices he is out of Arrows." << endl;
            system("pause");
        }
    }
}
```

The issue that I'm having is it seems that the for loop isn't initializing. Everything runs fine up to the "void fight" part of the program. How can I correct this?

Comment: `for (int x = arrowCount; x <= 0; x--)` should be `for (int x = arrowCount; x > 0; x--)` or you never enter the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean `for (int x = arrowCount; x >= 0; x--) {`? Note that the `for` loop conditional check is evaluated *before* the loop body is ran.

Currently your loop will terminate if `x` is positive, which judging from your variable name, is most likely to be the case.

Also note that the body of the `for` loop depends on neither `x`, nor `enemyCount`, which seems odd.

Comment: That helped, but now I'm only receiving my first if statement, which tells me that the x-- isn't functioning..?

Comment: See my last sentence. It might be a good time to get your debugger out.

Comment: Would it matter if the for loop depends on enemyCount or arrowCount? They seem interchangeable since both = 3. 

I've run it through the debugger, It's working better now, but I'm still only getting my first if statement for a return

Comment: I'm getting closer. I am now getting all three of my if statements to cout, but they are couting multiple times.

Comment: I got it to stop by using break. Thanks for the help.